# Using PInvoke to load a dll in Azure Service Fabric

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

So in my application, I have an actor that uses Pinvoke to call some functions defined in a win32 dll. I also have a front end webservice that calls these actors.

When I run this locally, everything works perfectly. The win32 dll is found and loaded correctly and my actors can call functions from there.

However, when I deploy my solution to Azure, I just get an internal server error when the actor tries to load the dll. Theres no descriptive error so I think that the actor either can't find the dll or can't find one of its dependencies. 
I already tried using dependency walker to figure out the dependencies. Most were typical windows binaries with the exception of vcruntime140.dll. I added this to the VS project as a resource file by right clicking on the Project and then navigating to Add>Existing Item and then editing the "Copy to Output Directory" property of the resource in the solution explorer to "Copy always".  Is this the right way deploying a native dll to service fabric? I'm also running in release mode so there shouldn't be any debug dll's needed.

Some extra information - My project was initially ported over from a web api project and I was able to successfully call functions in the win32 dll when hosting my web api on Azure in release mode.

Let me know if I need to provide some extra information

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out. For people who may stumble upon this later, here is how:

When I used dependency walker, I saw that I had immediate dependencies on vcruntime140.dll and msvcp140.dll. However, by digging deeper, I noticed that msvcp140.dll has an additional dependency on concrt140.dll. When I copied this over to my server's bin folder, I didn't get an internal server error anymore and I was able to call into my win32 dll.

All of these are visual studio c++ redistributable binaries that are usually found here "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.CRT".